# ASM - How the asm search the disks and where is this parameter from?

Tags: oracle, network, listener

I'm a begginer in Oracle ASM and when I will create a diskgroup the ASM shows me this parameter:

[image]

Where is this parameter from? I don't remember set any parameter with this name. I know that usually Oracle set this name as default when is not set a preferential parameter name, but in the creation process I don't saw this configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally it is the [ASM_DISKSTRING](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/ASM_DISKSTRING.html) parameter.

But the above screenshot shows that you use ASMLib, which uses a fix format for disks, starting with `ORCL:`.
Whenever you label a disk for ASMLib with `oracleasm createdisk`, that disk becomes available with the name starting with `ORCL:`.

So if you set `ASM_DISKSTRING` to `ORCL:*`, the ASM instance can find these disks. But as far as I remember, if you do not set anything, even then the ASM instance can find these disks.

By the way, you can also list these disks at `/dev/oracleasm/disks`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In my environment I've checked the parameter ASM_DISKSTRING and it's null and even like this the ASM can find.

Comment: Well, the cited docs say this about the default value of ASM_DISKSTRING: "The null string; Oracle Automatic Storage Management discovery finds all disks in an operating system-specific location to which the Oracle Automatic Storage Management instance has read/write access."

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the ASM_DISKSTRING initiallization parameter for your ASM instance.

[ASM_DISKSTRING](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-BF533461-03CF-42B0-9D9E-1E0AA1190826.htm#REFRN10248)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will see about this parameter.